# Create nested string literal union when you don't know intermediary types or names

Tags: typescript, hardhat, typechain

I am trying to create a union of string literals that are deeply nested.

Mostly, the structure looks like this:

```
typechainTypes.factories.contracts
|
|----->Lock__factory (extends ContractFactory)
|           |-----> contractName: string
|----->****** (this is a `export * as foo from bar`)
            |-----> ****** (want to extract only if it extends ContractFactory; Extract<Foo, ContractFactory> type didn't work)
                      |-----> contractName: stringcontractName: string
```

Pseudocode of what I want (where ** is any depth):

```
type ContractFactories = typechainTypes.factories.contracts.**.* extends ContractFactory ? ___ : never;
type ContractNames = ContractFactories['contractName'];
```

Put differently:

```
type LookForFactory<T> = T.flatMap(foo => {
    if (foo extends ContractFactory)
        return foo;
    else if (foo === undefined || foo === null || foo is SomePrimitive)
        return never;
    else
        return LookForFactory<foo>;
}
type ContractNames = LookForFactory<typechainTypes.factories.contracts>;
```

That is, it should be a union of:

```
typechainTypes.factories.contracts.Lock__factory.contractName
typechainTypes.factories.contracts.SomethingA.this_is_a__factory.contractName
typechainTypes.factories.contracts.SomethingB.SomethingC.this_is_a__factory.contractName
typechainTypes.factories.contracts.*.*.*.*.this_is_a__factory.contractName
```

If having an unknown depth is impossible, I'd settle for a union of:

```
typechainTypes.factories.contracts.Lock__factory.contractName
typechainTypes.factories.contracts.UnknownNameA.UnknownNameB__factory.contractName
```

Incidentally, the original way I was trying to do this was using `Parameters<ethers.getContractFactory>[0]`, but due to the final overload having `any` as parameter 0, this ends up being `any[]`, which isn't useful, and I haven't found a way to exclude the `any[]` override.

Thanks!

**Edit**: In response to Alex's answer below (since this won't all fit in a comment):
Alex proposed

```
type LookForFactory<T> = {
  [K in keyof T & string]:
    T[K] extends ContractFactory
      ? K
      : `${K}.${LookForFactory<T[K]>}`
}[keyof T & string]
```

This seems *almost* right, but not quite.
Doing `type ContractNames = LookForFactory<typeof typechainTypes.factories.contracts>;` results in `type ContractNames = "somethingA.metadata.opensea.OpenSeaSchema__factory.prototype" | "somethingA.utils.JSON__factory.prototype" | "somethingA.utils.JsonTest__factory.prototype" | ... 10 more ... | "Lock__factory.prototype";`

I think there are two problems with this: first, I'm getting a fully qualified name, and not the string literal itself (that `.prototype` probably needs to be replaced with `['contractName']` somehow). The other problem is that apparently not all of the "factories" directly extend ContractFactory, so rather than checking whether something extends ContractFactory, I think we need to check whether a `contractName` key exists.

To elaborate on that second bit:
`typechainTypes.factories.contracts.somethingA.AbstractRuleCascade__factory` resolves to something that has a `contractName` property but doesn't actually extend BaseFactory.

I tried this, which got closer:

```
type LookForFactory<T> = {
    [K in keyof T & string]:
    K extends 'contractName'
        ? T[K]
        : LookForFactory<T[K]>
}[keyof T & string];
type ContractNames = LookForFactory<typeof typechainTypes.factories.contracts>;
```

which results in `type ContractNames = LookForFactory<typeof typechainTypes.factories.contracts.somethingA> | "AppProtocolGame" | LookForFactory<typeof typechainTypes.factories.contracts.guessanumbergame> | LookForFactory<...> | "Lock"`

The visible possibilities that don't say LookForFactory there look correct. So it's very close.

It's worth noting that `typechainTypes.factories.contracts.somethingA` on mouseover says `import somethingA`; if I hit F12  on `contracts` it shows that it comes from `export * as somethingA from "./somethingA";`

**Second edit:**
This *seems* to work, but I'm not sure why adding NonNullable "fixes" it (other no-op utility types seem to similarly "fix" it):

```
type LookForFactory<T> = NonNullable<{
    [K in keyof T & string]:
    K extends 'contractName'
        ? T[K]
        : LookForFactory<T[K]>
}[keyof T & string]>;
```

results in `type ContractNames = "OpenSeaSchema" | "JSON" | "JsonTest" | "AppGateway" | "LApp" | "SanctionedRegistry" | "TurnsLimitRule" | "TurnsRule" | "AppProtocolGame" | "GuessANumber" | "GuessANumberRuleCascade" | "TicTacToe" | "TicTacToeRuleCascade" | "Lock"`

Comment: I did my best to parse this question, but it was hard. What input do what expect to yield what output, specifically? If you create a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with your test data as part of it, and what the expected type should be it would be a lot easier to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you want this:

```
type LookForFactory<T> = {
  [K in keyof T & string]:
    T[K] extends ContractFactory
      ? K
      : `${K}.${LookForFactory<T[K]>}`
}[keyof T & string]
```

This is a recursive conditional type.

1. First it maps over the `string` keys as `K` of the object type `T`.
2. If `T[K]` is a `ContractFactory`, then return that key.
3. If `T[K]` is anything else, then return `${K}.${LookForFactory<T[K]>}` which merges the parent key `K` with all matches in the `T[K]` object.
4. `[keyof T & string]` at the end indexes the object we just made by it's own keys to get the value types of that object as a union.

Let's try it out:

```
type ContractFactory = {
  contractName: string
}

type Typechain = {
  factories: {
    contracts: {
      Lock__factory: ContractFactory,
      SomethingA: {
        this_is_a__factory: ContractFactory,
        SomethingB: {
          this_is_a__factory: ContractFactory
        }
        not_a_factory: true
      }
    }
  }
}

type ContractNames = LookForFactory<Typechain>;
/*
"factories.contracts.Lock__factory" |
"factories.contracts.SomethingA.this_is_a__factory" |
"factories.contracts.SomethingA.SomethingB.this_is_a__factory"
*/
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gO2AJwIYGNgDEPDskKAXigG8AoKKdRFXAOVQFsIAuKAZxQEsEBzcgF9y5UJCgAVcBHQALVL2JlKUAGa583CB3YUqVGkjSYdy-foAycdAGsA+nfWZ8IdvCO4czggBoV5gGU4FmBZXj4AQV1-cyhQ7g47BLtUByc8AjdaY2wNXxjA4Ih4-gAhaNjY+MTk1Mc811hszwaC-WFKqgQ4YBT670aUAFcINo72lWFhUWkoKzgbLHwvDJAAHgkAPiU9KABtAGkoRRsIEDhVSSgAMk4efgBdVhiJQ4eoCAAPYAgEABMOE0PJgVi42gB+KAHNrsAAGABJSAdBAA6RHzRbLBobN6bQSwoR7U7nS4SG53ZDhB4iMTQdx0TCMFiAkgYpbIUEEDbSOQKBCbADc5AA9ML9AA9cFAA)

Comment: This is *very* close but not quite right. Due to limitations on formatting and length, I modified my question rather than explaining what didn't work here.

Comment: I figured out a solution based on your solution, but I'm not 100% sure why it works